# animation when finish first animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make two animation with CSS3.

How can I make the second animation, when the first is finished? I'll try with stylus too, but always have an error with the keyframes.

My codepen is:
http://codepen.io/Luiggi/pen/IenGu

Thanks, Luiggi

Comment: what is your second animation

Comment: @aelor I want to set 100% width of this div

Comment: you want the whole page to become red afterwards , right ?

Comment: yes, that's the animation, like a curtain! :P

Answer (score 1):

here is what you need to do :

you must specify the attributes you want to change at different stages of your animation :

```
@keyframes luiggi {
    0% { height: 0%; width: 0.09%; left: 50%;}
    50% { height: 100%; width: 0.09%; left: 50%;}
    100% { height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0%; }
}
```

updated pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nchpy)

Answer (score 1):

thanks @aelor but I found my solution.

You must to create the 2 @keyframes and then, you must to write the css rule like this

```
.escenario {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 0.09%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -o-transition: 2s all;
    -ms-transition: 2s all;
    -moz-transition: 2s all;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all;
    transition: 2s all;
    -o-animation: luiggi 2s, locura 2s 2s 1;
    -ms-animation: luiggi 2s, locura 2s 2s 1;
    -moz-animation: luiggi 2s, locura 2s 2s 1;
    -webkit-animation: luiggi 2s, locura 2s 2s 1;
    animation: luiggi 2s, locura 2s 2s 1
}
```

In **animation** , write the first animation, comma and the second one

Comment: Thank the lord you figured this out yourself lol. I was sitting here right the code so to answer this for you, though it's good for you to have figured this out yourself.

Comment: Thanks to you too, I always have a questions, my second day with the animations, but I need more level to make something cool!

Comment: Oh you can go so far with this. I'd check out adding transform and other new CSS to your Animation for a real curtain feel ;)